# Open folder commands not working (firefox, vscode ..)

Tags: cinnamon, desktop-environment

I have strange problem where commands like "Show in Folder" in Firefox or Chromium are not working (nothing happens). Also, right-click "Open Containing Folder" in vscode does nothing.

[image]

I'm using *Cinnamon* and therefore *Nemo* as the file manager. No special settings i can thing of..

Answer (score 0):

With Cinnamon Desktop, check *Settings -> Prefered Application* for Files. In my case somehow vscode was put in here. Other Desktop environments should have similar settings. Or use [`xdg-mime`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_MIME_Applications) if you prefer CLI.

[image]